# useParams() is empty in react-router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm trying to render the params in the url as an h2 in in the website. But even when I try console.log useParams is empty.

Here's my Router.js file

```
const Webpages = () => {
    return (
        <Router>
            <Routes>
                <Route exact path="/" element={Home()} />
                <Route exact path="/comics" element={Comics()} />
                <Route path='/comics/:comicId' element={Comic()} />  <--------------
                <Route exact path="/portfolio" element={Portfolio()} />
                <Route exact path="/blog" element={Blog()} />
                <Route exact path="/contact" element={Contact()} />
                <Route exact path="/store" element={Store()} />
                <Route path="*" element={NotFound()} />
            </Routes>
        </Router>
    );
};

export default Webpages;
```

Here's my comic component

```
import React from 'react';
import NavBar from '../../components/NavBar';
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';

function Comic() {
    let { comicId } = useParams();
    console.log(comicId);

    return (
        <div>
            <NavBar />
            <p>{comicId}</p>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Comic
```

The page element when I go to a random comic works fine, like *localhost:3000/comics/465456* but the

tag is empty and the console log is undefined, it's also undefined if I just try to console log useParams()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are directly invoking the React function. Directly invoking React functions is ***not*** how React works.

The `Route` component's `element` prop expects a `React.ReactNode`, a.k.a. JSX. Pass the components as JSX. The JSX is transpiled down to vanilla Javascript and the React framework handles calling your function within the confines of the React component lifecycle.

Example:

```
const Webpages = () => {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
        <Route path="/comics" element={<Comics />} />
        <Route path='/comics/:comicId' element={<Comic />} />
        <Route path="/portfolio" element={<Portfolio />} />
        <Route path="/blog" element={<Blog />} />
        <Route path="/contact" element={<Contact />} />
        <Route path="/store" element={<Store />} />
        <Route path="*" element={<NotFound />} />
      </Routes>
    </Router>
  );
};
```

Comment: thank you! I didn't knew there was a difference but it makes sense now, I'm sure I've done this mistake a few times before. This solved the problem perfectly.